# System-provided prompt for inAppReview for Flutter, iOS, and Android

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, kotlin

I am using [in_app_review](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review)
package in flutter for in app review, but I found no way to change the system-provided prompt in the dialog.

I think there is no way to change it even if you use inAppReview natively(is this true?).

[iOS guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ratings-and-reviews)

[Android guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#design-guidelines)

Answer (score 1):

> there is no way to change it even if you use inAppReview natively . is this true?

Yes, these are native dialogs that are provided by the OSes' stores. You can't really tamper with them.

Comment: I don't know the Braze library, but it's something different than https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/3566727-requestreview